# How can i read all files from a directory and do operations parallelly?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose I have some files in directory and i want to read each file and extract the file name and first row from the file (i.e header) for some validation. How can we do this in spark (using python).

```
input_file = sc.textFile(sourceFileDir)
```

By `sc.textFile()` we can read all files parallelly but using map we can apply any rules or function to each element in the rdd. I am not understanding how can i fetch only file name and one row of all files using `sc.textFile()`

Currently, I am doing these requirement (mentioned above) using a for loop.

```
files = os.listdir(sourceFileDir) 
for x in files:
    **operations**
```

How can i do the same in parallel manner to all files that will save some times as there are lots of files in the directory.

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textFile` is not what you are looking for. You should use `wholeTextFile`. It creates a rdd with key as FileName and value as content. Then you apply a map to get only first line:

```
sc.wholeTextFiles(sourceFileDir).map(lambda x : (x[0], x[1].split('\n')[0]))
```

By doing that, the output of your map is the fileName and the 1st line.

Comment: just a little correction wholeTextFile  returns
RDD representing tuples of file path and the corresponding file content

Comment: Thanks @Steven.. 1 Ques: Is there any known challenges or issues for wholeTextFiles() ?

Comment: @A.N.Gupta I dont think so. The output is different from `textFile` but there are both fine depending on what you want to do.

Comment: @Steven it is working fine. Is it possible to get the size of each file ?

Comment: @A.N.Gupta you can count the number of char and compute some size based on that ... I am not sure it is the ideal way. An otherway is to use "hdfs dfs -ls" cmd line to retrieve this information